# How do I specify docker run args when using a dockerfile agent in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am setting up a simple jenkins pipeline with a dockerfile agent, Jenkinsfile as follows:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    dockerfile {
        dir 'docker'
    args '-v yarn_cache:usr/local/share/.cache/yarn'
    }
}

environment {
    CI = 'true'
}

stages {

    stage('Build') {
        steps {     
            sh 'yarn install'
            sh 'yarn run build'
        }
    }

    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'yarn run test'
        }
    }
}
```

}

I would like the yarn cache persist in a volume so I want the image to be started with '-v yarn_cache:usr/local/share/.cache/yarn'. 
With the given Jenkinsfile, jenkins stalls after creating the image. 
The args parameter is not actually documentented for the dockerfile agent but for the docker agent.
Do I really have to use a predefined (and uploaded) image just to be able to use parameters ? 
Cheers Thomas

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured it out: 
It actually works just like I configured it only I have forgotten the leading / in the volume path. So with

```
args `'-v yarn_cache:/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn'`
```

it works just fine..